# Using Janosh's svelte-multiselect package, how can I format selected items to form a horizontal list?

Tags: typescript, multi-select, sveltekit

Example code:

```
<script lang="ts">
    // @ts-ignore
    import MultiSelect from 'svelte-multiselect'
    let valuesSelected: string[]
    
</script>

<div>
    <MultiSelect 
        id="values"
        name="values"
        type="object"
        allowUserOptions="append"
        options={[]}
        placeholder="Enter values" 
        bind:value={valuesSelected}
        required
        >
        <span let:option slot="selected" class="selected-item">
            {option}
            <span style:background={option} style=" width: 1em; height: 1em;" />
        </span>
    </MultiSelect>
</div>

<style>
    :global(ul.selected) {
    /* :global(div[class*="multiselect"] > ul > li) { */
        /* CSS styles for the body */
        display: inline;
    }

    :global(div.multiselect > ul.selected > li[class]) {
        background: var(--sms-selected-bg, rgb(255, 138, 28));
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
</style>
```

Looking around for similar answers online, I always see that the `display` variable in the parent `<ul>` tag should be set to `inline`. Though this doesn't solve my issue.

Ideally, I'd want the selected values to show up side-by-side like how they are in the example given here (https://multiselect.janosh.dev/#--examples). So it appears that it can be done.

[image: janosh svelte multiselect side-by-side values example]

Here's a svelte.dev link to that example above (https://svelte.dev/repl/e3b88f59f62b498d943ecf7756ab75d7?version=3.59.1). The package author created this, though it doesn't look like repl is set up to handle it.

I have a feeling that using a framework (Pico CSS) may be causing issues.

Comment: It was Pico CSS that was causing this issue. Not sure why though.